# Openlayers2 map icon name missing

Tags: javascript

This is my code.

function insertNodes(data) {
    Anodes = {};

```
var node, id;

$.each(data, function(item, value) {

    if (item == "A") {
        $.each(value, function(i, object) {
                id = object['Aid'];
                node = new MapNode(id);
                node.name   = object['name'];
                node.lat    = object['lattitude'];
                node.long   = object['longitude'];

                node.addElement();
                Anodes[id] = node;
        });

    }
});
```

}

Similarly, there is another function for B's.On loading the page all A's and B's should be loaded from database and it is working properly now.But after loading the page, some A's are not displaying their display name.Sometimes this problem also happens with B's .I think this is a problem with the javascript code. Please help me to clear this little problem.

Comment: Please provide a small demo to reproduce your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask